# The top of the floated image is not in line with the text

Tags: floats, alignment, emacs

It looks fine in the first picture, but notice in the second one, the top of the picture is not in line with the text.

[image]

In the second picture the shift happens because I added a paragraph before the picture.

I'm using Emacs Org Mode for exporting to PDF. Org uses the LaTeX engine. I can insert LaTeX code in the document when I edit it but I prefer having all the settings in a separate file, like so, and then write the document just like a markdown document:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: org-plain-latex % This is equal to article class
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper, 11pt]

#+LATEX_HEADER: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in]{geometry}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{hyperref}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tocloft} % Spacing between TOC items

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont{Charis SIL Compact}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmonofont{Hack} % font used for code blocks

#+LATEX_HEADER: \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setlength{\parskip}{1em}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{microtype}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{graphicx}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{wrapfig} % Allow images to be floated

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{titlesec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{booktabs}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{awesomebox}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{enumitem}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setlist{topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt, itemsep=-2pt}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \titlespacing\section{0pt}{10pt}{-4pt}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{10pt}{-4pt}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{10pt}{-4pt}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat\paragraph{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titlespacing\paragraph{0pt}{10pt}{-4pt}
```

How can I make the top of the image align with the text as in the first picture?

Comment: Note we cannot do much with an org file, please provide a full but minimal LaTeX file instead. You can substitute `\rule{5cm}{5cm}` for your image. Note that wrapfigs usually do not align with the top by default. This is not related to `org` mode.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a flag to set wrapfig to align with the text? I haven't found anything in the wrapfig docs.

Comment: That is the problem, there is a setting, but it has to be set _outside_ `wrapfig`. You should be able to find it on the site if you search wrapfig

Comment: You might try with the `insbox` (a plain TeX macros package) `InsertBoxR` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\intextsep` is a space added above and below a float in the **middle** of the main text.

That is the reason for the misalignment you are seeing after adding a paragraph before the wrapfigure figure.

To set `\intextsep = 0pt` just for wrapfigures  add to your preamble:

`\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}}`

[image: A]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allow images to be floated


\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY dummy text

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a test I}
\end{wrapfigure}


1. \kant[1]

2.  \kant[2]

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a test II}
\end{wrapfigure}

3.  \kant[3]

\end{document}
```